# Community and old question poke

Tags: support, community-user

If we look at community user profiles ([meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) as well as [main](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)), we can see:

> Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some
>   attention

So sometimes I see old question poked and put on the front page of active questions. Most of the time when I see this, it is about a question with some tags with some answers from me: For example this morning I saw only poked questions with the tag [emacs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs).

Does anyone see the same question(s) poked or is it user dependent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everybody sees the same question that is poked (maximum of one such question per hour), so it's independent of the user. It is dependent on the question though, and as mentioned in the [Community user profile](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) - old and unanswered. More specifically, questions eligible for bumping have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be locked or closed).

Meta reference:

- [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/168244)

Comment: Thank for the answer and in particular the "eligiblity of bumped questions"